# log4cpp - no default constructor exists for log4cpp::AppenderSkeleton

Tags: c++, inheritance, logging, log4cpp

I've recently linked log4cpp in my project and I tried making a class as such:

```
class ConsoleAppenderSkeleton : public log4cpp::AppenderSkeleton
{
     private:
        Console& console;

     public:
        ConsoleAppenderSkeleton(Console& console) : console(console)
        {
          // Error! no default constructor exists for log4cpp::AppenderSkeleton
        }
}
```

**What I tried**

- Adding another constructor: `ConsoleAppenderSkeleton(void);`
- Removing the initializer list

Any idea what could be causing this? I'm aware I need to implement the inherited functions such as close() however those shouldn't be causing this error, and in C++ you aren't *forced* to override, it will just behave in a weird manner if you don't

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the base class' constructor explicitly and it doesn't have an empty constructor. Its constructor requires an std::string parameter. You should notice this when you override a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class GameConsoleAppender : protected log4cpp::AppenderSkeleton
{
    private:
        Console& console;

    public:
        GameConsoleAppender(const std::string& name, Console& console) : 
            AppenderSkeleton(name),
            console(console)
            {
                std::cout << "Constructor called.";
            }
};
```

This was the answer. I had to inherit its base constructor with the string, then added my own referencing. If anyone else has this problem, just add the base consrtuctor:

AppenderSkeleton::AppenderSkeleton(const std::string& name)